# Пароль на страницу,хранящийся в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте,имеется секретная страница,на которую можно зайти только через страницу логина,введя там пароль.Нужно что бы пароль брался не с самой страницы,а с БД.

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");  
$db = mysql_select_db("mydb");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");
if(!$connection || !$db) {
    exit(mysql_error());
}

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `password` FROM `pass` WHERE `id` = '30'");
mysql_close();

$p = $result1['password'];

if($_GET['key'] !=md5('$p')) {
    header('location:login.php');
}

?>
```

на строчке переменной `$p` ошибку `echo` выдает,помогите плз, как правильно оформить.

Сама ошибка:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in Z:\home\Cascade\www\enter\30.php on line 13

Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы.

Comment: Укажите в какой именно строчке есть ошибка и текст самой ошибки. Иначе все это гадание на кофейной гуще

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in Z:\home\Cascade\www\enter\30.php on line 13
Если пишу через echo
Без него вообще на секретную страницу не заходит.

Comment: Переменные в одинарных кавычках в php не интерполируются. Т.е. не заменяются содержимым перемнной. Так что `'$p'` представляет собой именно строку $p. В приведенном коде вообще отсутствует `echo` так что такой ошибки в данном тексте быть не может. И брать md5 от значения из базы странно, было бы логичнее в базе держать md5 от пароля а не открытый пароль

Comment: Спасибо,что то протупил,за переменную в кавычках:)
Премного благодарен.

Comment: @JohnTRavolta, эм... в вашем примере кода **нет** конструкции `echo`... Так что именно находится в 13-й строчке?

Comment: $p = $result1['password']; - это 13 строчка, я после = вставлял echo,после чего выдавало ошибку,а стоило всего на всего кавычки убрать.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вам нужно обработать результат запроса. Например:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `password` FROM `pass` WHERE `id` = '30'");
mysql_close();
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result1);
$p = $row->password;
```

Comment: Не помогло,на страницу просто не заходит.Без echo заходит но с ошибкой(в данной строке $p = $result1['password'];),а без echo вовсе не заходит.